Adding certificate to Fiddler on request
I want to use Fiddler as a proxy for debugging purpose. Without fiddler everything works perfectly fine.
I have to add a certificate to my HTTP request. My code looks like this:
constructor TSpecialHTTP.Create(adbconn: IDBConnection; ...);
var
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  dbresult: Variant;
  q: IDataset;
begin

  ... other unimportant database stuff

  // http is a private variable of the TSpecialHTTP class
  http := TIdHTTP.Create;
  // fiddler debug
  http.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
  http.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;

  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(http);
  ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
  http.IOHandler := ssl;

  http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  http.Request.UserAgent := 'MyApplication';
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := false; // without it doesn't work, dunno why
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values[c_version] := GetMyVersion;
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + token;
  CreateGUID(guid);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values[c_message_id] := Copy(GUIDToString(guid), 2, 36);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values[c_generating_utc] := DateToISO8601(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(now), true);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values[c_version] := cdhrecords[cdht].version;
  http.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

  certstream := TBytesStream.Create;
  if not VarIsNull(dbresult[1]) then begin
    SaveVariantToStream(certstream, dbresult[1]);
    certstream.Position := 0;
    certstream.SaveToFile(certfile);

    ssl.SSLOptions.CertFile := certfile;
    ssl.SSLOptions.KeyFile := certfile;
    ssl.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmBoth;
    ssl.OnGetPassword := GetPassword;
  end;
  
  ... again unimportant stuff
end;

I tried to add following line to Fiddler script on static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {:
oSession["https-Client-Certificate"] = "C:\\temp\\cert.pfx";

This is what I get in Fiddler as a request:

POST https://api.example.com/cdh/v1.0/Message/Product HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 56494190
version: 1.0
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <key>
message-id: 18EE53A3-64D0-4B34-9527-2D92F15FD462
generating-utc: 2024-09-04T07:46:44.363Z
signature: <signature>
Host: api.example.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: MyApplication


And this is what I get as a response:

HTTP/1.1 401 Missing certificate or authorization header
Keep-Alive: true
Content-Length: 0
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:1c288406-24f1-4c26-9015-e7bdd006594a
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2024 07:46:46 GMT
Connection: close


What do I have to do to make it work with Fiddler as a proxy?

"I want to use Fiddler as a proxy for debugging purpose" - why? Indy has its own built-in way to debug its transmitted data. You don't need Fiddler for that. Simply assign a TIdConnectionIntercept-derived component, such as one of the TIdLog... components, to the TIdHTTP.Intercept property, and it will log all of the unencrypted HTTP traffic (it will log before the SSLIOHandler encrypts outgoing data, and after it decrypts inbound data)

Your main problem you are trying to provide a pfx/PKCS#12 file that contains the HTTPS client certificate:

oSession["https-Client-Certificate"] = "C:\\temp\\cert.pfx";


However the documented way to use a HTTPS client certificate in Fiddler [Classic] is:


Install the certificate in the Current User's Personal Certificate Store.
Right-click the certificate in Personal Certificates Store.
Click All Tasks > Export... as .CER file


This exported certificate is then set via Fiddler script:
oSession["https-Client-Certificate"] = "C:\\temp\\cert.cer";

That means the private key and the certificate have to be present in the Windows personal certificate store and the file you set to oSession["https-Client-Certificate"] is only a certificate without private key. This file/certificate is used by Fiddler to identify which certificate/private key it have to use from Windows personal certificate store.

A .CER file does not actually contain the private key for the certificate. The local CER merely acts as a pointer to a certificate in your Personal Certificates store-- that certificate, installed the Windows Personal Certificate store (certmgr.msc) contains the private key. (Source)


There is also a third-party Fiddler extension called "Fiddler Client Certificate Select" https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons. This could be useful, if you are testing with multiple certificates.

and at this post @Robert shows how to use different certificates depending on the URL with FiddlerScript (very useful in my use case!)

@complete_stanger: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79011364/defining-a-clientcertificateprovider-in-fiddlerscript/79042779#79042779 I wrote a FiddlerScript which creates a  "Default Client Cert"-Button with which you can choose a certificate from your local certificate store as default client certificate.
